# Why is the sleep method affecting/not showing my updated JTextArea on the panel?

Tags: java, jframe, sleep, jtextarea, timeunit

I have a window that has various panels. On one panel, I have a JTextArea called dogTalk where I update its text. 
Upon user's click of a button, I want the text to add what I have mentioned below in setText.

I used the sleep method so that the user can read my updated text and the window can close automatically within 4 seconds. 
(I don't want the user to have the ability to close the window on close, hence I didn't use Jframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE but used JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE and used my automatic closing with the help of sleep and system.ext(0))

However, I noticed that the sleep method does not allow the dogTalk to get updated. It prints out "we're working", though, so I am guessing it's a problem with the window? 
I know that the sleep is causing the issue and not something else in my code because when I commented out the sleep and system.exit(0) and tested if my if statement is executing, I noticed the JTextArea did update with my statement just fine! 
Could you please help me?

if (e.getActionCommand().equals("buybone")) {

```
        System.out.println("We're working");
        dogTalk.setText(dogTalk.getText() + "\nWow bone very wow much thanks bye.");
        try
        {  
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e1 )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

       System.exit(0);
```

}

Comment: It's because you're calling `sleep` on the Event Dispatch thread (inside `actionPerformed`)

Comment: oh so i take it out from actionPerformed ? where would i put it then?

Comment: You should spawn a new thread. The JVM exits when all non-daemon threads are no longer running. Spawn a new thread that waits for 4 seconds, then have it call `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> frame.dispose())`, which should end the Event Dispatch Thread, removing the need for the nasty `System.exit` call

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling `System.exit`, let the application gracefully die out. An application terminates when there are no non-daemon threads still alive. Daemon is just a flag used to determine whether the JVM should terminate if that thread is still running; the JVM will still terminate if non-daemon threads are running.

With that said, the problem is that you're calling `sleep` on the Event Dispatch Thread.

The EDT handles all updating and rendering of Swing and AWT components, as well as execute the behavior specified in event listeners (like `ActionListener#actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`). If you cause it to block (through sleeping or other forms of blocking), it won't be able to process updating and rendering. When you call `setText`, the EDT needs to be able to adjust the text. You're preventing this by forcing it to sleep.

**How to fix**

Spawn a new thread, have it wait 4 seconds, then have it dispose of your frame:

Java 8+

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     dogTalk.setText(...);
     new Thread(() -> {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
          frame.dispose();
     }).start();
}
```

Before Java 8

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dogTalk.setText(...);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed response!  When I copy pasted your thing:  new Thread(() -> {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
          frame.dispose();
     }).start();

It gave me a syntax error and told me to delete these tokens. I think your }before ).start is confusing it (and me, I am not sure why we need that?)

Comment: @user1217 It's a lambda expression, you need Java 8 as well as an IDE that supports it's features. I'll edit my answer, but you should really update your development environment

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry, I use what's required for class. Thanks for updating your response–Now I don't have any errors in my code and it's working!! Thanks SO MUCH!!!! I am honestly so grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Just right after `dogTalk.setText(dogTalk.getText() + "\nWow bone very wow much thanks bye.");` put the following code :

```
dogTalk.revalidate();
dogTalk.repaint();
```

Comment: Well you don't need repaint AND revalidate; they are both targeted for different situations (revalidate actually causes a repaint-like action, also updates component hierarchy after invalidating it). I'm on my phone, so no, I didn't try it. But you should look into what those methods do. `setText` calls `insertString` on it's document, which triggers the event listeners of the document. It should update on it's own

Comment: yeah, didnt work :( when I added those 2 statements, it was the same as before. thanks though :)

Comment: So try the following code using a timer : Timer t= new Timer(2000, null); t.setRepeats(false); t.start(); Use this instead of using the sleep which sops for a while the main thread. Tell me if it gets better.

Comment: unfortunately, when i do that, it doesnt pause for even a second but closes immediately after i press the button.

Answer (score 0):

the following code works well
i used Frame.update function it worked.
in your case you have to update panel i guess

```
           dogTalk.setText(dogTalk.getText() + "\nWow bone very wow much thanks bye.");
        frame.update(getGraphics());
        try
        {  
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e1 )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
```

this is my full program

```
public class TestSleep extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JTextArea are=new JTextArea("asdjkfh");

JButton button=new JButton("Submit done");

public TestSleep()
{
    are.setBounds(20, 20, 30, 10);
    button.setBounds(10, 50, 20, 20);
    this.add(are);
    this.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TestSleep sleep=new TestSleep();
    sleep.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    sleep.setVisible(true);
    sleep.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 280);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
        System.out.println("Working");
        are.setText(are.getText() + "\nWow bone very wow much thanks bye.");
        this.update(getGraphics());
        try
        {  
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e1 )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);

}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't manually invoke the `update` method of components (it calls [`paint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-), which shouldn't be called manually), nor [access the graphics of a component](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15991175/2398375) manually

Comment: But it *shouldn't* be called, as the documentation says.

Comment: can you give me link to that document ?

Comment: I did, click `paint` in my first comment: "*Applications should not invoke paint directly*"

Comment: i did not get you ? you mean you used textarea.paint() ? I tried that  too     . when i set text to textarea and get text it gives me new text but it is not updated in textarea that is why i tried to paint frame itself then it worked.

Comment: Nooo, I mean I linked you to the documentation in my first comment. [Here is the link again](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-)