# Adding some pictures to a BuffredImage then Save it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist, sprite-sheet

My general idea is to make a Sprite-Sheet-Maker I mean the program will:

> 1. Collect more than one picture like "1.bmp" , "2.png" and "3.jpg"
> 2. Create new BuffredImage variable and draw on it the 3 pictures (and draw the BuffredImage on a JPanel on the same time)
> 3. Save the final picture "Final.png"

I'm thinking to make the First step and the Second one in one loop because i have a `JList` with the paths of all the pictures.

and to do that I used Java window Builder on eclipse, I made my form and I tried to test a simple code on the `Panel`.

```
Panel panel = new Panel(); //Work
panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE); //Work
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(5,5,5); //Work
Graphics g = null ; //Work
panel.paintComponents(g); //work
g.setColor(Color.BLACK); //ERROR---------------------ERROR
g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

The problem it's not only in that code but in all the idea so please *any of your ideas could help* me even a part of solution for a part of my project , so please comment with any idea you've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 g.setColor(Color.BLACK);//error
```

Since

```
  Graphics g = null ;//null value, you are not create any obeject
```

Upon `null` value we can't perform any operation.

You have to override `paintComponent` method in `JPanel` class then you will receive `Graphics` object.

```
      JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        frame.add(panel);//added to frame.
```

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986677/drawing-an-object-using-getgraphics-without-extending-jframe)

Comment: OK , how to relate the "Graphics g" with the JPanel ??

Comment: you want to add to panel?

Comment: i want to be able to draw on the jpanel

Comment: override `paintComponent` method. see that link

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a JPanel using a `GridLayout`.
2. Create 3 JLabel each containing an Icon for each image. Then add each label to the panel.
3. To create an image of any Swing component you can use the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.