# Java drawLine() not working

Tags: java, methods, graphics, line

I need help with this code. My g.drawLine(0,0,300,300) is not working. It was working until monday, I don't know what is going wrong. I use the g.drawLine(0,0,300,300) in order to test before using the plota_pixel() method. g.drawLine(0,0,300,300) shoud print a line from (0,0) to (300,300) on the Jpanel panel

MainView Class:

```
package alexandre.VIEW;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainView {

private JFrame janela;
public JPanel panel;


public MainView()
{
    janela = new JFrame("Exercicio 15/09");
    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel();
    this.ShowView();
}

public void ShowView()
{
    janela.pack();
    janela.setSize(750,600);
    janela.setLayout(null);
    janela.add(panel);
    panel.setBounds(0,0,710,600);


    janela.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("OIdsazxc");
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);    
    g.drawLine(0,0,300,300);

}

public void plota_pixel(int x, int y)
{
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);

}
```

}

Starter Class:

```
package alexandre.CONTROL;

import alexandre.VIEW.MainView;


public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainView view = new MainView();     
    view.ShowView();

}
```

}

Comment: I've already tryied to set                                           panel.setBounds(0,0,710,600);                                                                          before adding it to the JFrame

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I still get an empty gray panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using and drawing with the `Graphics` object from `panel.getGraphics()` does not work (see below links for the "why"). You will have to override the method "paintComponent" for the the JPanel, where the input parameter is the `Graphics` object

(Also quick note - standard method naming has the first letter lowercase so `ShowView()` should be `showView()`)

```
public MainView()
{
    janela = new JFrame("Exercicio 15/09");
    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel() {
       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);                   
           g.drawLine(0,0,300,300);
       }
    };
    this.showView();
}


public void showView() {
    janela.pack();
    janela.setSize(750, 600);
    janela.setLayout(null);
    janela.add(panel);
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 710, 600);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    janela.repaint();
}
```

Check out the following stack overflow question

[Drawing an object using getGraphics() without extending JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986677/drawing-an-object-using-getgraphics-without-extending-jframe)

And this resource (it's also in the linked question)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Answer (score 0):

You should set the panel visible as the last thing in the `ShowView`method.

```
public void ShowView()
{
    //your code
    janela.setVisible(true);
}
```